# connectivity of android with sql server 2008 r2 via c# webservice

Tags: c#, android, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been searching for a way to connect my android application with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Previously I have worked on mysql-android base code which use php ... and have used json parser in android code.

I don't know how to connect with SQL Server via c# webservice.

Please reply with example for doing so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have searched web for such problem...some solutions are there but they use ksoap2 library which is having different coding approach than json... I'm much more comfortable with json type android coding.. is there any way to use coding which will use android-json-c# webservice-database? if any?

Answer (score 1):

Why your task is 'I have been searching for a way to connect my android application with SQL Server 2008 R2'? Your android application doesn't connect to any database, it connects to web service. But web service really connects to database. So in fact you need to connect your web service to SQL Server.

There are two obvious ways:

- a) update your php web service to use SQL Server
- b) redesign your web service using c#

Both ways need separate discussion after you make your decision.

Comment: Oh..so how can I redesign my web service using c#? Any example would be much helpful

Comment: As theese are Microsoft technologies you can start with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742186(v=vs.90).aspx) or [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/#Samples)